# whether sql query secured from googlebots attack(google sql injection)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, sql-injection

Please verify for whether my sql query is safe enough from google sql attacks

```
<a href="secondpage.php?name=men">men</a>
```

The above link is going to next page and passing the name variable which is having men as the value...
and in second page,i m executing my sql query as follows.

```
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];

$lcSearcharr=explode("-",$lcSearchVal);
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
$lcSearchWord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $lcSearchWord);
$lcSearchWord = preg_replace('/%/', '\%', $lcSearchWord);
    $parts[] = '`Description` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';

}


    $countsql2='SELECT * FROM xml WHERE  ('.implode ('AND',$parts).')';
    //print($countsql2);
    $countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $countsql2) or die("Cannot Get Pname Info: (".mysql_error().")");
    $androws = mysqli_num_rows($countsql3);     

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countsql3)) {
       $countArray1[] = $row;   
       }
```

Please check whether my sql query is safe from google sql injection or not.

Comment: Google sql attack? That's the first I've heard of

Comment: may be i used wrong term.Please help on google sql injection

Comment: So what do you understand by *Google SQL injection*?

Comment: Its like google can harm ur website while crawling if ur queries are not correctly written.please help me on my query quality regarding google sql injection....

Comment: This is the topic: http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/11/google-bots-doing-sql-injection-attacks.html - it can happen when malicious sites construct malicious links and the Googlebot follows them. It does not need to be specifically protected against - the same protections against individual users directly acting maliciously will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Google SQLi attack? i think you have miss understand if google curl your website and adds kind of "Malicious" chars that harm your website this is not because they want to this is because you don't filter you query from the user.

as it looks like in your code you do filter you query by use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

if want to use mysqli to escape your string you can do something like:

```
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];
$query = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM xml WHERE Description LIKE ?');
$query->bind_param('s', $lcSearchVal);

$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
// then run while fetch_assoc() or similar loop to fetch the data.
```

basically never trust the user no matter google or just a simple user always validate the data because it can be manipulated.

read more in here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that a search engine’s bots may harm your site via an SQL injection by themselves is rather improbable. Search engine bots only follow links found on other web pages.

So if it actually happens that a search engine bot triggers a harmful SQL injection, there already must have been another web page with a link to your web site containing the SQL injection payload, e. g.:

```
<a href="http://example.com/secondpage.php?name=' evil SQL code …">
```

However, your code looks safe.